# Using microprofile-config-api: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @ConfigProperty

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, microprofile

I playing with the mpConfig-1.2 feature, but it seems to not work in my setup.

Using Liberty 18.0.0.2.

Have added the maven dependency for microprofile-config-api, CDI is working fine, but the @ConfigProperty is failing at startup with the message

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application demo-service-ear {1.0-SNAPSHOT}.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0004E: An exception occurred while starting the application demo-service-ear {1.0-SNAPSHOT}. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @ConfigProperty
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @ConfigProperty private no.klp.bpm.task.KOPSTask.endpoint2
  at no.klp.bpm.task.KOPSTask.endpoint2(KOPSTask.java:0)
```

The annotation is like this:

```
@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name="rule.engine.host", defaultValue="ukjent!")
private String endpoint2;
```

What can be possible wrong here ?

/bwa

Comment: looks like you have not added the dependency properly.
can you post your pom.xml or gradle or ivy file?

Comment: Well, the dependency IS correkt, but for some reason this fixed the problem in the enterpriseApplication config in the server.xml:

        <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, third-party" ...
        </classloader>

to

        <classloader commonLibraryRef="db2lib,MongoLib">
           .....
        </classloader>


So, for some unknown reason apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, third-party"  kills the mpConfig

Comment: have you tried enabling the feature in the server.xml with <feature>mpConfig-1.2</feature>?

Comment: sofarsoghood, it works fine now

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: see my comment from Sept 11, there it's described

Answer (score 2):

## Background info:

This is a classloader visibility problem, which will mainly exist when older configurations (e.g. pre-2017) are carried forward to apps that make use of MicroProfile.  In Liberty, APIs were classified into the following categories:

- `api` (e.g. JavaSE APIs)
- `spec` (e.g. JavaEE APIs)
- `ibm-api` (e.g. `com.ibm.websphere.*` APIs)
- `third-party` (e.g. `org.eclipse.persistence.*` APIs from the JPA 2.1 feature)

By default, `api,spec,ibm-api` are visible to applications, meaning `third-party` is not (because third party libs may may breaking changes, which would violate Liberty's zero migration policy).

Then, when MicroProfile features came along, they didn't fit into any of the above API categories (not universally standard enough to be considered `spec`, but more stable than `third-party`), so we made a new API type visibility:

- `stable` (e.g. `org.eclipse.microprofile.*` APIs)

The new `stable` API type was now enabled by default, so applications could see those APIs.

## Explanation of issue:

Since you had your `apiTypeVisibility` hard-coded to `spec, ibm-api, api, third-party`, this actually excluded the new `stable` API type, which MicroProfile APIs were categorized under. To fix this issue, you could specify:

```
<classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, stable, ibm-api, api, third-party"/>
```

This is pretty verbose though, and all you are really trying to do is enable `third-party` APIs to be visible, in addition to whatever you get by default. For this reason, as of 18.0.0.3 you can now use "chmod style" syntax to grant or revoke the individual API types with `+` or `-` signs. For example, the above `<classloader>` config is equivalent to:

```
<!-- Read as: In addition to default values, also grant 'third-party' api type visibility -->
<classloader apiTypeVisibility="+third-party"/>
```

### Additional resources:

- [Classloader configuration element doc](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/config/#application.html)
- [Accessing third-party APIs from a Java EE application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_3p_apis.html)

Comment: Great info, even that, it's hard to know the difference of the api